# Use of SYSNAME data type in/out TSQL procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, types

I'm trying to figure out the use of datatype `sysname` and how the parser implicitly converts and/or recognizes **none-quoted-literals**. Using the famous function [object_id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) for testing existence, Consider this.

```
--Sanity test
begin
    if object_id('NotExistingProcedure','P') is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
end
go

--This works.
begin
    declare @ObjectName sysname = 'NotExistingProcedure',
            @ObjectType sysname = 'P';
    if object_id(@ObjectName,@ObjectType) is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
end
go

--This does not.
begin
    declare @ObjectName sysname = NotExistingProcedure,
            @ObjectType sysname = P;
    if object_id(@ObjectName,@ObjectType) is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
end
go

--But this works.
create procedure TestExists
    @ObjectName sysname,
    @ObjectType sysname
as
    if object_id(@Objectname,@ObjectType) is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
go

exec TestExists NotExistingProcedure,P;
```

Can anyone please explain why using none-quoted-literals to assign variables of type `SYSNAME` works when passing parameters to a procedure but not outside.

Answer (score 2):

[`SYSNAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx):

> **The sysname data type is used for table columns, variables, and stored
>   procedure parameters that store object names.** The exact definition of
>   sysname is related to the rules for identifiers. Therefore, it can
>   vary between instances of SQL Server. sysname is functionally the same
>   as nvarchar(128) except that, by default, sysname is NOT NULL. In
>   earlier versions of SQL Server, sysname is defined as varchar(30).

Now in your example that does not work:

```
begin
    declare @ObjectName sysname = NotExistingProcedure,
            @ObjectType sysname = P;
    if object_id(@ObjectName,@ObjectType) is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
end
go
```

Error:

> *Invalid column name 'NotExistingProcedure'.*
>
> *Invalid column name 'P'.*

Based on [`DECLARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) documentation

```
DECLARE 
{ 
    { @local_variable [AS] data_type  | [ = value ] }
  | { @cursor_variable_name CURSOR }
} [,...n]
```

[image]

So you could assign `value` where:

> = value
>
> Assigns a value to the variable in-line. The value can be a **constant** or an **expression**, but it must either match the variable
>   declaration type or be implicitly convertible to that type.

Then [`Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx):

[image]

So the parser expects **column name**, but there is no column name (because it is not a [`SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) statement).

That is why you get error:

> **Invalid column name 'NotExistingProcedure'.**

---

Now let's move on to last example that works:

```
create procedure TestExists
    @ObjectName sysname,
    @ObjectType sysname
as
    if object_id(@Objectname,@ObjectType) is not null print N'Exists.';
    else print N'Not exists.';
go

exec TestExists NotExistingProcedure,P;
go
```

Based on [`EXECUTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

[image]

So as you see you could pass `value`:

> value
>
> Is the value of the parameter to pass to the module or pass-through command. If parameter names are not specified, parameter
>   values must be supplied in the order defined in the module.
>
> **If the value of a parameter is an object name, character string, or qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks.** If the value of a parameter is a keyword, the keyword must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

That indicates that is should be closed with `'`.

If you try to pass with schema:

```
exec TestExists dbo.NotExistingProcedure, P;
go
-- Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

And you need to enclose it with

```
exec TestExists 'dbo.NotExistingProcedure', P;
go
```

When it is keyword you could quote it with `[]`:

```
exec TestExists [from], P;
go
```

---

To sum up:

1. You cannot pass unquoted name when declaring variable of type `SYSNAME`.
2. You cannot pass unquoted name with `EXEC` when it is keyword or contains schema name
3. Could not find documenation why passing unquoted literal works